# Why can't I delete a remote git branch with git push origin :branchname?

Tags: git

When I try to push to a remote git branch to delete it with `git push origin :branchname` I get the following error message:

> error: unable to push to unqualified destination: remotes/origin/branchname
>   The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
>   begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.

But when I type `git branch -a` I still see it in `remotes/origin/branchname`. Why can't I delete it remotely?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The branch has already been deleted in the origin repository. You can reflect this in your local remotes when you fetch by doing `git fetch --all --prune`, which will delete it from your remotes. You can also more specifically do `git remote prune` to just prune your remotes without updating.

Comment: It's actually acceptable to ask a question you know the answer to, or quickly find the answer to, especially if providing the answer here will be useful to others searching for it. I don't see a duplicate of this question anywhere, either, though I will admit I didn't search very hard. :-)