# How can I hide the "pr" remote branches?

Tags: git, github, branch

I have **GitHub** for Windows installed. When I run "git branch -a", it shows many remote tracking branches, and they appear to be pull requests.

One co-worker who uses **Git** for Windows doesn't see this, but another co-worker who also uses **GitHub** for Windows sees the same result.

Example: I forked "bootstrap-sass". On github.com, I used the "Clone in desktop" button. It opens GitHub for Windows, and adds the new repo to my list of local repos.

Running "git branch -a", it returns over 100 results, most of them are "/pr/#". Below is a small sample:

```
C:\gh-ui\bootstrap-sass [master]> git branch -a
  bower
* master
  remotes/kenshub/2.0-stable
  remotes/kenshub/2.1-stable
  remotes/kenshub/HEAD -> kenshub/master
  remotes/kenshub/gh-pages
  remotes/kenshub/master
  remotes/kenshub/next
  remotes/origin/bower
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/pr/3
  remotes/origin/pr/4
  remotes/twbs/2.0-stable
  remotes/twbs/2.1-stable
  remotes/twbs/gh-pages
  remotes/twbs/master
  remotes/twbs/next
  remotes/twbs/pr/1
  remotes/twbs/pr/10
  remotes/twbs/pr/103
```

I'm guessing it's GitHub for Windows. How can I hide the "pr" remote branches? Is it a git config, or part of the "Clone in desktop" command?

Comment: If I use "git clone" through command line, I don't get the extra "/pr/" remote tracking branches. If I use "Clone in Desktop", GitHub for Windows is doing something extra, and I end up with a bunch of "/pr/" remote tracking branches. What more is GitHub for Windows doing, and what else is different than a plain "git clone"? See this 2.5 minute video screencast:
http://screencast.com/t/oSS43ednMHyZ

Comment: I've never had this problem until a recent update to GitHub for Windows. Very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

When cloning a repo, don't use the "Clone in Desktop" option if you have GitHub for Windows installed. Instead, copy the clone URL and run `git clone <url>` through command line.

When you clone through GitHub for Windows, it is running extra commands like:

```
fetch origin +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/* +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --prune
status --untracked-files=all --porcelain -z
```

If you don't want to re-clone the repo, then refer to the other answer about deleting branches, and make sure you don't have a fetch refs congif to get "/pr/" branches. View your `.git/config` file, or run `git config --list --local`.

Comment: To see what commands are being run by GitHub for Windows, view the debug log. Click on the gear, `About -> Open Debug Log`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide, you you could delete those remote tracking branches.
Following "[Can you delete multiple branches in one command with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3670560/6309)", you can try something similar to:

```
git branch -D `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/remotes/*/pr/*`
```

(or you can use [other expressions with awk and xargs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10555315/6309))

This is similar to [deleting one remote tracking branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3046478/6309).

But understand that it is a temporary solution: the next fetch, if configured by default `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, would bring back *all* remotes branches.
As explained in "[Git Internals - The Refspec](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-The-Refspec)", you can also configure multiple fetch in order to bring only the remote tracking branches that you want to see.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I couldn't get the different options for deleting multiple branches to work. I did learn about the fetch refs config. I'll add a comment to my question with a video showing the issue in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to manually edit the .git/config file and don't track all upstream branches but specific ones.

```
[remote "upstream"]
  url = https://github.com/xyz/xyz.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
```

Replace the '*' with specific branch name

```
[remote "upstream"]
  url = https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-java.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/1.0.x:refs/remotes/upstream/1.0.x
```

Then you need to delete remote tracking branches one by one

```
git branch -d -r upstream/0.2.x
```

[Deleting the references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046436/how-do-you-stop-tracking-a-remote-branch-in-git/3046478#3046478) - this don't delete remote branches, it just removes from local.

[Batch pruning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555136/delete-multiple-remote-branches-in-git/10555315#10555315) - this deletes the remote branchs